# Using CustomCredentialsAuthProvider in JsonServiceClient

Tags: servicestack

I try to implement my own custom CredentialsAuthProvider. The server seems to work fine with the following implementation:

```
public class MyCustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName == "testuser" && password == "1234")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens,
                                                Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        session.FirstName = "Testuser Joe Doe";

        authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
        return null;
    }

}
```

When I call on my Browser http://localhost:8088/auth/credentials?UserName=testuser&Password=1234 I get back a page containing a session ID and the testuser Joe Doe. Looks fine.

Now I try to call this from my Windows WPF client. I have created a Login Page and a LoginViewModel class since I implement the MVVM pattern. But I do not understand, what I really have to set the provider property in the Authenticate class to.

In my WPF class I have the following:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public JsonServiceClient ServiceClient { get; private set; }

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();           
    }
    // ....
}
```

And then in my LoginViewModel I have a Login() method which is a RelayCommand implementation of the login button like so (The form contains also a field where you have to enter the name of the application server since there is more than one. This is why I compose the baseUri in the handler):

```
    private void Login()
    {
        var baseUri = $"http://{AppServer}:8088";
        ((App)Application.Current).InitServiceClient(baseUri);
        var client = ((App) Application.Current).ServiceClient;

        //var response = client.Send<AuthResponse>(new Auth { UserName = "Test", Password = "TestPassword" });
        var authResponse = client.Post(new Authenticate
        {
            provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name, // <-- WHAT SHOULD THIS BE???
            UserName = "testuser",
            Password = "1234",
            RememberMe = true,
        });
        // .... 
    }
```

`CredentialsAuthProvider` is unknown by the compiler. What do I need to pass here and what assemblies do I need? So far I have:

- ServiceStack.Ckient
- ServiceStack.Interfaces
- ServiceStack.Text
- MyService.ServiceModel  //DLL containing the DTOs etc., NO implementations

What am I missing and doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CredentialsAuthProvider.Name](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/501ad4c5b5f077956d94c4254d981b8e4e548381/src/ServiceStack/Auth/CredentialsAuthProvider.cs#L28) just provides typed access to the ["credentials"](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/501ad4c5b5f077956d94c4254d981b8e4e548381/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthenticateService.cs#L27) string literal, which you can use in its place, e.g:

```
var authResponse = client.Post(new Authenticate
{
    provider = "credentials",
    UserName = "testuser",
    Password = "1234",
    RememberMe = true,
});
```

You can find the list of [Auth provider literals](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#auth-provider-routes) in the Authentication docs.